# When using a Builder Pattern why shouldn't I reuse the builder-object to access the object configuration?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder, delegation, builder-pattern

when using a [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) why shouldn't I reuse the builder-object to access the object configuration?
For example:

Normal way:

```
ObjectA(ObjectBuilder b) {
    this.a = b.getA();
}
public Object getA(){
    return this.a;
}
```

But why can't I just use this:

```
ObjectA(ObjectBuilder b) {
    this.builder = b;
}
public Object getA(){
    return this.builder.getA();
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The whole point about using a builder is to build immutable objects: the builder is mutable, the thing it builds isn't. If you delegate to the builder, your instance is mutable again: anybody who has a reference to the same instance of `ObjectBuilder` can change your `ObjectA`. If you want a mutable object, there is no need for the builder: just have setters on your `ObjectA`.

Comment: That's a pretty good answer. It's true I don't want A to be changed after the constructor. That's why I used the builder in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A large reason for using a builder is to build an immutable object: the builder is mutable, the thing it builds isn't (necessarily).

If you delegate to the builder, your instance would be mutable again: anybody who has a reference to the same instance of `ObjectBuilder` can change your `ObjectA`. This means that any checks you do on the validity of the state of the `ObjectA` at construction time can be invalidated.

If you want a mutable object, there is no need for the builder: just have setters on your `ObjectA`.

Comment: If you want a mutable object, there is _less_ need for the builder. Builders are good for more than just immutability.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have similar question on Builder pattern [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206286/how-to-clone-old-builder-to-make-a-new-builder-object). Wanted to see if you have can help me out over there.